# Initial condition perturbation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Let $f\in \mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^n,[0,T])$, and we define the following Backward/Foward ODE : for a small $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x^{\epsilon}(t)=f(x^{\epsilon}(t),t), & t\in [0,T] \\
x^{\epsilon}(\epsilon)=x_0,
\end{cases}
$$
I want to prove that $x^{\epsilon}$ is well defined on $0$ : Using Picard's theorem we have local existence of a solution $x^{\epsilon}(.)$ in a neighborhood of $\epsilon$ (for example :$]\epsilon-a,\epsilon+a[$ ($a>0$) but how to prove the following statement :

There exists $\epsilon_0>0$, such that $\epsilon<\epsilon_0$ : $x^{\epsilon}$ is well defined on $0$.

Comment: How does the equation depend on $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @FrederikRavnKlausen : In the initial condition, $t_0(ϵ)=ϵ$.